# How to fix cheksum error while deploying artifacts to Nexus repository using Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm new to jenkins and I'm trying to deploy jar file of a maven project as well as it's pom.xml file. While deploying, I've faced a warning: Checksum validation failed.
PS: I've created a pipeline using different jobs.
You will find below the configuration I made in jenkins's Nexus job:

```
Nexus Artifact Uploader:

Nexus Version: NEXUS2

Protocol: HTTP

Nexus URL: localhost:8081/#admin    

Credentials: ***

GroupId : com.oumayma

Version : 1.0-SNAPSHOT

Repository: additionproject

Artifacts:

          Artifact:

             ArtifactID: additionproject

             Type: jar

             Classifier:

             File: C:\Users\OUMAYMA AMRI\.jenkins\workspace\AdditionprojectBuild\target\additionproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    

          Artifact:

             ArtifactID: additionproject

             Type: pom

             Classifier:

             File: C:\Users\OUMAYMA AMRI\.jenkins\workspace\AdditionprojectBuild\pom.xml
```

Here below the console output of the running job :

> Uploading artifact additionproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started....
>
> GroupId: com.oumayma
>
> ArtifactId: additionproject
>
> Classifier:
>
> Type: jar
>
> Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> File: additionproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> Repository:additionproject
>
> Downloading:
>   http://localhost:8081/#admin/content/repositories/additionproject/com/oumayma/additionproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>
> 52 % completed (4.1 kB / 7.9 kB).
>
> 99 % completed (7.9 kB / 7.9 kB).
>
> [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected http://localhost:8081/#admin/content/repositories/additionproject/com/oumayma/additionproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>
> [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected http://localhost:8081/#admin/content/repositories/additionproject/com/oumayma/additionproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>
> Downloaded:
>   http://localhost:8081/#admin/content/repositories/additionproject/com/oumayma/additionproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>   (7.9 kB at 127 kB/s)
>
> Failed to update metadata
>   com.oumayma:additionproject:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not
>   parse metadata C:\Users\OUMAYMA
>   AMRI.m2\repository\com\oumayma\additionproject\1.0-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-additionproject.xml:
>   entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: TEXT
>   seen
>   ...t:8081/static/rapture/resources/favicon-32x32.png?_v=3.18.0-01&_e=...
>   @14:124)
>
> ERROR: Uploading file additionproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar failed.
>   Finished: FAILURE

Here is my settings.xml:

```
<settings>
    <server>
      <id>Nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>additionproject</id>
          <name>Addition project</name>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>

          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/additionproject/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        </repositories>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
      <id>additionprojectmirror</id>
      <mirrorOf>additionproject</mirrorOf>
      <name>Addition project mirror</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/additionproject/</url>
    </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Comment: Can you please post your settings.xml file you are using?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes sure, I've edited the post and added the settings. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Usually you should have a mirrorOf `*` within [your settings.xml which means everything you are consuming is redirected through the Nexus repository manager](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/maven-and-other-build-tools/apache-maven).  Now the question is: How does your distributionManagement configuration look like?

Comment: @khmarbaise Here is my distributionManagement configuration: 


`<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>additionproject</id>
            <name>additionproject</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/additionproject/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement> ` 


I will add as well the mirrorOf * in my settings.xml.

Comment: This is simply wrong...you have to have one entry for snapshot repository and one for release repository in distributionManagement (see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management)

Comment: @khmarbaise I've tried all your propositions but sadly none of them worked for me, I've been struggling in this error for so many days with no solution. Thank you so much for your help.